# How to read from two COM ports?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm writing code that reads from a COM port.  I want it to read from two ports without having to close the first port and open the second one.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: What platform, what frameworks, what've you tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
using System.IO.Ports;

...

SerialPort port1 = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
SerialPort port2 = new SerialPort("COM2", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);

port1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port1_DataReceived);
port2.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port2_DataReceived);
port1.Open();
port2.Open();

...

private void port1_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
    Console.WriteLine(port1.ReadExisting());
}
private void port2_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Show all the incoming data in the port's buffer
    Console.WriteLine(port2.ReadExisting());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create TWO CommPort objects and open them both. Just 'new' them both up, set the parameters for each comm port and have at it.

Comment: I'm not sure, that's what I was wondering.

Comment: Stated in this way it is more a comment than an answer.

Comment: This **is** an answer but given the difficulty the OP is having, a _good_ answer needs to really spell everything out.